# What does "The invocation of the constructor on type that matches the specified binding constraints threw an exception." mean?

Tags: silverlight, silverlight-oob

What does "The invocation of the constructor on type  that matches the specified binding constraints threw an exception." mean in silverlight?

Answer (score 27, accepted):

Silverlight called your constructor, and your constructor threw an exception.

You can find the original exception from your constructor in the `InnerException`.